# Trouble trying to execute jQuery code using jQueryUI dynamic loaded Ajax tabs

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Hi
I'm using jQueryUI tabs in index.php file
I have 4 tabs and 4 files. I load each tab content using the jQueryUI Tabs Ajax functionality

Each file has its own jQuery plugins and code, but **my problem is that when I load (for example) contact.php in the Contact tab, the jQuery code in contact.php doesn't work or fire**.

I've seen the ***.ajaxComplete()*** function, but it is "dirty", because *it forces me to move back all the code from each file to the index.php file*, and **my point was to separate code and have everything more clean**.

Also, google maps doesn't work when being loaded dynamically in jQueryUI Tabs...

Comment: Do you have any sample code to post?

Answer (score 0):

As per [http://docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...my_slider.2C_Google_Map.2C_sIFR_etc._not_work_when_placed_in_a_hidden_.28inactive.29_tab.3F)

Any component that requires some dimensional computation for its initialization won't work in a hidden tab, because the tab panel itself is hidden via display: none so that any elements inside won't report their actual width and height (0 in most browsers).

There's an easy workaround. Use the off-left technique for hiding inactive tab panels. E.g. in your style sheet replace the rule for the class selector ".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide" with

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}
```

For Google maps you can also resize the map once the tab is displayed like this:

```
$('#example').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.panel.id == "map-tab") {
        resizeMap();
}
});
```

resizeMap() will call Google Maps' checkResize() on the particular map.